# gcd of polynomial values

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, divisors-multiples

Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are two coprime polynomials in $\mathbb Z[x]$.  I'm interested in any sort of upper bound on $gcd(f(a),g(a))$, in terms of the integer $a$.  Are there any results of this type?  I'm fairly open about the exact nature of the upper bound, but I don't know where to start looking. If it helps, I'm even willing to assume that $g(x) = x^b$ for some $b$.

Comment: The resultant should give you a first upper bound.

Comment: Have a look at this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.07936

Comment: You can run the Euclidean algorithm of $\mathbb{Q}$ and clear denominators to get a universal bound: there are integers p,q,r so that pf(x) +qg(x) =r and if you evaluate at $a$ the gcd f(a) and g(a) must divide $r$.